# Stubbing instance method using Sinon and Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have written test case for below function (i have left out a lot of unnecessary code and provide only essential stuff but let me know if you need any other info).

```js
static getLibs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const instance = new LibClass();
    instance.loadLibs().then((libs) => {
      if (!libs) {
        return LibUtils.createLib();
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
      }
    }).then(resolve).catch((err) => {
      //log stuff here
    })
  })
}

export default class LibClass {
  //constructor
  //method
  createLib() {
    return new Promise(() => {
      //some stuff
    })
  }
}
```

```js
describe('Library', () => {
  it('should get libs', () => {
    let obj = new LibClass();
    let mstub = sinon.stub(obj, 'loadLibs').returns(Promise.resolve('success'));

    return LibWrapper.getLibs().then((res) => {
      expect(mstub.called);
    }, (err) => {
      //log stuff
    })
  }).catch((exp) => {
    //log stuff
  })
})
```

But whenever I run above test case, stub method is never called.
Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In your tests how is your test `LibClass` connected to your `LibWrapper`?

Comment: You are creating your stub on the obj which is an instance of LibClass but you call LibWrapper.getLibs which create a new instance.

Comment: @Troopers   So is there any way to test these kinds of scenarios?I have been wracking my brains but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the stub on the `LibClass` prototype instead of creating it on an instance. If you do this, then you'll need to restore it after the test so it doesn't pollute your other tests:

```
describe('Library', () => {
  let mstub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mstub = sinon.stub(Libclass.prototype, 'loadLibs').returns(Promise.resolve('success'));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mstub.restore()
  });

  it('should get libs', () => {
    let obj = new LibClass();

    return LibWrapper.getLibs().then((res) => {
      expect(mstub.called);
    }, (err) => {
      //log stuff
    })
  })
})
```